# Application Center mobile client - cannot login via HTTPS connection

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I have prepared an environment where the appcenter mobile client installed on iOS devices are able to browse through the available apps and install them. After making sure it worked, we moved the environment into HTTPS, with the SSL certificate installed on a reverse proxy and the configuration in the JNDI for app center done.

With this, i managed to browse to the installers catalog via the device browser, i.e. the installers.html page. After getting the AppCenter mobile client installed, i then try to login  to the server via the mobile client via a HTTPS URL. Instead i hit an error:

```
Connection failed. Check your connection details (Could not connect to the server).
```

The URL i use is

```
https://mydomain.com/applicationcenter
```

with the SSL option set to `ON`

I suspect that i would need to install the SSL cert in the installer for the mobile client. Is that the case? Any pointers for this is welcomed. The Worklight version is 6.1

Thank you

**EDIT**

After checking the cert, it seems that the cert we acquired from the public CA (Verisign in our case) is not in the list found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5012

Will this give any implication that we need to manually install the cert into the device for it to work?

Comment: What does it say in the connection details? It should tell you if there was an SSL error, and if there is it would probably mean that you have to manually install the certificate into the device.

Comment: What happens when you try to browse to that URL from a desktop computer?  Can you try (if you can get to a Linux or Mac OS command line) to run "openssl -connect mydomain.com:443" and let us know what the output is?  Does the certificate configured on the server contain the server certificates for all the intermediate servers up to the root CA, or does it just contain the server certificate?

Comment: i tried different URL and it seems that i would need to specify the port 443 for it to work, hence using `mydomain.com:443/applicationcenter` as the server URL managed to get me login. Thanks both.

Comment: @ipohfly, please write this as an Answer so others could benefit from this as well.

Comment: Just as information (as I know the original problem is already solved) - the command I suggested above should have said "openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:443".  Sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by specifying the SSL port 443 in the URL, so the URL to use is:

```
mydomain.com:443/applicationcenter
```